# Unity Panels disable themeselves instead of showing animations

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I have this minor problem with c# in Unity game I'm making.

I have 2 panels on my screen and on screen tap those panels should dissapear from the screen with animation, but instead they just disapper.

Here's my code:

```
public class PanelManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static PanelManager instance;

    void Awake(){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        }

    }


    public GameObject PanelUp;
    public GameObject PanelDown;
    public GameObject TapText;
    public GameObject score;
    public Text highScore;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        highScore.text = "Highscore: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("score");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void GameStart() {
        TapText.SetActive (false);
        score.SetActive (true);
        PanelUp.GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("MenuUp");
        PanelDown.GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("MenuDown");
    }

    public void StopAnimations() {
        TapText.SetActive (false);
        PanelUp.SetActive (false);
        PanelDown.SetActive (false);
    }

}
```

And I'm calling those functions like this (inside other class):

```
private void Update ()
    {
        if (gameOver)
            return;

        if (!started) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                started = true;
                PanelManager.instance.GameStart ();
                if (started = true) {
                    PanelManager.instance.StopAnimations ();
                }


            }
        } else {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

                if (PlaceTile ()) {
                    SpawnTile ();
                    scoreCount++;
                    scoreText.text = scoreCount.ToString ();
                } else {
                    EndGame ();
                }
            }
        }

        MoveTile ();

        // Move the stack
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,desiredPosition,STACK_MOVING_SPEED * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving enough time for your panel animation to finish. You call `PanelManager.instance.GameStart ();` which will start the animation but right after you call `PanelManager.instance.StopAnimations ();` which deactivate the panels so you won't see the animation.

To fix that issue you could use a Coroutine that would wait the amount of time needed for your animation to finish.

So if for example your animation last 1 second you could have a Coroutine like this

```
IEnumerator PlayAnimation()
{
    PanelManager.instance.GameStart ();

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    PanelManager.instance.StopAnimations ();
}
```

And you can call the Coroutine by just doing

```
StartCoroutine(PlayAnimation());
```